# Updated Meteor JS file doesn't refresh automatically in Cloud9 runtime

Tags: meteor, cloud9-ide

I installed meteor on Cloud 9 and can run simple apps such as OOTB sample or tutorial successfully. When modifying a HTML or CSS file, the change shows up in browser automatically. However, if I change a JS file, the runtime console indicates the app is rebuilding but browser get stuck and won't update until I restarted meteor and reload the page. Using Chrome debugger I found websocket keeps failing prior to restart.

Anyone can help troubleshooting? I am OK even if I have to reload the page in browser (F5) to pick up the update, just don't want to restart server every time.